# install-info error

Tags: software-installation, software-center

When I try to install Kmplayer from Ubuntu Software Center this happens, what should I do? Thanks.

```
installArchives() failed: 
Extracting templates from packages: 32%
Extracting templates from packages: 65%
Extracting templates from packages: 98%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...

Extracting templates from packages: 32%
Extracting templates from packages: 65%
Extracting templates from packages: 98%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...

Extracting templates from packages: 32%
Extracting templates from packages: 65%
Extracting templates from packages: 98%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/etc/environment: line 1: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121/bin: Is a directory
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
Error in function: 
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/etc/environment: line 1: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121/bin: Is a directory
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
```

Comment: Did you alter your `/etc/environment` file at some point?  It's likely malformed.

Comment: I'm new to the Ubuntu. Can you  explain me what does that mean, please? Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Ward suggested the problem is in the `/etc/environment` file.
In my case I added two variables for Java - `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME`. I just removed them and now everything works fine.